# Operations on items of dictionary object in list, if duplicate found

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

If dictionary object in list  is duplicate based on two or more items , then these two object should be merged by doing arithmetic operation on items.

Example -> 'CUSTOMER' and  'ID' item makes duplicate. 'USAGE' item should be added resulting object.

First 'COUNTRY CODE' should be retained in resulting object,  if it differs.

Input :

```
[
  {
    "CUSTOMER": "XYZ",
    "COUNTRY CODE": "US",
    "ID": "Essential",
    "USAGE": 500
  },
 {
    "CUSTOMER": "XYZ",
    "COUNTRY CODE": "US",
    "ID": "Seats",
    "USAGE": 20
  },
 {
    "CUSTOMER": "XYZ",
    "COUNTRY CODE": "FR",
    "ID": "Essential",
    "USAGE": 50
  }

]
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "CUSTOMER": "XYZ",
    "COUNTRY": "US",
    "ID": "Essential",
    "USAGE": 550
  },
 {
    "CUSTOMER": "XYZ",
    "COUNTRY CODE": "US",
    "ID": "Seats",
    "USAGE": 20
  }
]
```

Comment: How did you decide that country code should be US for the second item in the output?

Comment: thanks,  It was typo. corrected now

Comment: You have commas missing between dicts in the list

Comment: I think what @jpp means is how can you merge those two dicts when they have different country code? Do you have to choose the first or what?

Comment: Yes , first country code should be retained if it is different.

Comment: You should specify your requirement in the question. An example is a nice (and often essential) help, but a specification if necessary: have all dictionaries the same 4 keys? what it the *precise* criteria for merging 2 of them? is merging adding the `"USAGE" key values, and what are the values for the 3 other keys? All that should be clear in the question - and IMHO it is not currently :-(

Comment: @serge , thanks for your humble feedback

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use a 3rd party library such as `pandas` for this task.

Given list of dictionaries `J`, you can perform a `groupby` and then convert `to_dict`.

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(J).groupby(['CUSTOMER', 'ID'])\
                     .agg({'USAGE': 'sum', 'COUNTRY CODE': 'first'}).reset_index()\
                     .to_dict(orient='records')

print(res)

[{'COUNTRY CODE': 'US', 'CUSTOMER': 'XYZ', 'ID': 'Essential', 'USAGE': 550},
 {'COUNTRY CODE': 'US', 'CUSTOMER': 'XYZ', 'ID': 'Seats', 'USAGE': 20}]
```

You can also use `collections.defaultdict` with some messy `if` statements. I think the `pandas` way is cleaner and more easily adaptable.

Comment: Nice one - I'll need to remember pandas is there.

Answer (score 0):

Nice little exercise!

Here's my take on it. We'll need to sort the list, then compare pairs:

```
customers.sort(key=lambda cust:cust['CUSTOMER'] + cust['ID'])
result = []
previous_cust = None
for cust in customers:

    if not previous_cust:   # first time though
        previous_cust = cust
        continue

    if previous_cust['CUSTOMER'] == cust['CUSTOMER'] and\
       previous_cust['ID'] == cust['ID']:
            previous_cust['USAGE'] += cust['USAGE']
    else:
        result.append(previous_cust)
        previous_cust = cust

result.append(previous_cust)  # tidy up
result
```

gives:

```
[{'CUSTOMER': 'XYZ', 'COUNTRY CODE': 'US', 'ID': 'Essential', 'USAGE': 550},
 {'CUSTOMER': 'XYZ', 'COUNTRY CODE': 'US', 'ID': 'Seats', 'USAGE': 20}]
```